# Batch file login system

Tags: windows, batch-file, authentication, cmd, system

I am making a login system for my OS. And there is a error i dont know how to fix it

```
@echo off
color 02
IF NOT EXIST Users md Users
:start
:menu
cls
echo                                  ZEROS 0.2.1 LOGIN
echo.
echo [1]-Sign in
echo [2]-Register
echo [3]-User List
echo [4]-Exit
echo.
set /p input=Your choice:
if %input%==1 goto log
if %input%==2 goto reg
if %input%==3 goto ucheck
if %input%==4 exit
echo Invalid Choice
pause
goto menu
:reg
cls
color 02
echo                              ZEROS 0.2.1 REGISTER
echo.
set /p user="Enter new username: "
echo %user%>>"Users\userlist.txt"
cls
echo                              ZEROS 0.2.1 REGISTER
echo.
set /p pass="Enter new password: "
echo %pass% >> "Users\%user%.txt"
goto menu
:log
cls
echo                              ZEROS 0.2.1 LOGIN
echo.
set /p user="Username: "
cls
echo                              ZEROS 0.2.1 LOGIN
echo.
set /p pass="Password: "
@echo off
set /p password=<Users\%user%.txt
@echo off
if %pass% equ %password% call console.bat
pause
goto menu
:ucheck
IF NOT EXIST Users (
cls
echo There are no users.
pause
goto start
)
:users
if not exist Users\userlist.txt (
goto reg
)
cls
cd Users
echo                             ZEROS 0.2.1 USERS
echo.
type userlist.txt
pause
goto start
```

When i choose 3rd option one time, it works well, but if i choose 3rd option 2 or more times, it shows that there are no users. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's because `Users\Users` doesn't exist.  At some point you `cd Users`, but never `cd ..`.  Logic problem.

I suggest instead of `cd`, use `pushd Users`, then `popd` when you want to return.  You should also `setlocal` at the top of your script.  [See this page](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) for an explanation of why this is important.

And don't be afraid to add double line breaks between sections and indents in your parenthetical code blocks to improve the readability of your code.  This script is about as readable as assembly.  :P